# Auto increase version code after each build in Android

Tags: android, build, gradle

Is there a way to auto increase version code after each build in Android? I'm using Gradle.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting but there is no way to do this.

Comment: u can add it as a feature request for adt plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a custom build.gradle file that does the trick here: [link](http://andreborud.com/android-studio-automatic-incremental-gradle-versioning/)

Comment: thanks so much, also I found another way, see here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/HelloVersioning